# How to dump a file to a Hadoop HDFS directory using Python pickle?

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I am on a VM in a directory that contains my Python (2.7) class. I am trying to pickle an instance of my class to a directory in my HDFS.

I'm trying to do something along the lines of:

```
import pickle

my_obj = MyClass() # the class instance that I want to pickle

with open('hdfs://domain.example.com/path/to/directory/') as hdfs_loc:
    pickle.dump(my_obj, hdfs_loc)
```

From what research I've done, I think something like [snakebite](https://github.com/spotify/snakebite) might be able to help...but does anyone have more concrete suggestions?

Comment: Snakebite doesn't write to hdfs. https://github.com/spotify/snakebite/issues/227

Answer (score 2):

If you use PySpark, then you can use the **saveAsPickleFile** method:

```
temp_rdd = sc.parallelize(my_obj)
temp_rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsPickleFile("/test/tmp/data/destination.pickle")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a work around if you are running in a Jupyter notebook with sufficient permissions:

```
import pickle

my_obj = MyClass() # the class instance that I want to pickle
local_filename = "pickle.p"
hdfs_loc = "//domain.example.com/path/to/directory/"
with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(my_obj, f)
!!hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal $local_filename  $hdfs_loc
```

Comment: how to write it model to hdfs from python script and not jupyter notebook?

Comment: how to write python script for dumping a model using pickle to hdfs

Answer (score 0):

You can dump Pickle object to HDFS with [PyArrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/index.html):

```
import pickle
import pyarrow as pa

my_obj = MyClass() # the class instance that I want to pickle

hdfs = pa.hdfs.connect()
with hdfs.open('hdfs://domain.example.com/path/to/directory/filename.pkl', 'wb') as hdfs_file:
    pickle.dump(my_obj, hdfs_file)
```